# Loading multiple PHP files simultaneously to speed up page load time

Tags: php, mysql, page-load-time

I have developed a HTML5, PHP/MySQL website that uses 1 local and 1 remote MySQL database. When a user logs into the site he is presented with a 'Homepage' that displays (Depending on the user) between 1 and 10 jQuery [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

Each tab executes a PHP include command to include a self contained block of code that opens a DB handle to the remote DB, fetches a SQL result, processes and closes it, opens a handle to the local DB, fetches a SQL result, processes that and closes it, then outputs a HTML table. This table is then displayed in the tab.

The problem is that with multiple tabs on show, (4+), the page loading time is getting a bit slow, sometimes up to 10 seconds. The site is on a hosted server which I assume has a fast connection to the remote DB, (Unlike my XAMPP development setup).

Is there a way of speeding up the page load time?

I was thinking along the lines of making the content of each tab an iframe, which would open the associated block of 'table making' code for that tab. Of course this would mean that for a Homepage with 5 tabs the browser would effectively be opening 6 pages, (The Homepage and 5 tabs which are independent pages in themselves).

Or is there a smarter way of achieving a faster page load?

Comment: It depends on how you're handling the connection to the database? Perhaps if you're constantly creating a new connection, only creating the one and using that across the 4 tabs may be useful.

Comment: It does not make sense to _guess_ what is the bottleneck in your case, you will have to measure the performance of the single step to find out where it makes sense to invest time. One general approach though probably is to reduce the number of database communications required. Think about using some caching layer.

Comment: I am opening and closing connections to the databases for the content of each tab. This is causing overheads but is simplifies the code, as one tab may not need the SQL results of another, and it is easier to compartmentalise the code this way with no cross-tab dependencies. I have run timing tests on the tab code blocks and it seems that multiple accesses to the remote DB is the major slowdown, hence why I thought that using iframes (Which admittedly I haven't tried yet), might be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use sessions? It might be the session locking. Call session_write_close() as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the session_write_close() tip, but each tabs code block does not open and close sessions, only the 'Homepage' opens a session, then includes the tabs code blocks as necessary.